# box-shadow overridden by div background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with adding shadows to a list of block elements. The Divs in this case have a background-color which overrides the shadow from the div above. To solve this i decrease the z-index on each element, but that is not a valid solution.

How would you solve this issue on a better way in pure html/css? And how would you solve this using Twitter bootstrap?

Here is my test code HTML/CSS

```
<div class="container" style="z-index:10">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="container" style="z-index:5">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="container" style="z-index:0">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
 </div>


h1{margin:0;}
.container{
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/42816g0x/5/

Some clarifications:
- the shadow needs to be on the div.container

- the div should be able to have different bg colors, eg every odd div
- the number of div.container can vary, I don't want to manually add z-index on each

Edit 2:
I came up with a solution which I think is the best one, I don't need to manually fiddle with the z-index, (because they are dynamically added through x nr items, varying times to times). Instead I use the pseudo class ::before to add shadow on the top.

```
.container::before{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.34) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 58%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.34)), color-stop(58%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.34) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.34) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.34) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.34) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#57000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have made some changes in css and html.

```css
   h1{margin:0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.container{
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
 </div>
```

Using **Twitter bootstrap**, check this:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/42816g0x/)

**EDIT:** ok, you got the solution. That's good. Here is another option for your first EDIT question. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/5jhw7ytf/1/) This is using jquery. You can add following script code and jquery, jquery UI as shown in DEMO. You don't need to add `z-index` manually. `z-index` can get applied to multiple `div`.

```
$(function() {
    var boxes = $("div");
    var z = 4;
        boxes.each(function() {
            $(this).zIndex(z--);
        });
});
```

Comment: The shadow should not be on the heading, rather on the div. The div can contain more than just the heading.http://jsfiddle.net/42816g0x/5/

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/y5c5z638/)

Just add position:relative for the z-index to work for you:

```
.container{
position:relative;
background-color: yellow;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 }
```

Comment: Exactly, forgot that line in the example. But I want to solve this in a smarter way. the container is computed and not manually written, the z-index is not a good way to add manually. There got to be a better solution.

Comment: You left out the  important info that they are dynamic. Please update your question since it's not possible to guess your code.You can easily use a class for z-index. .z1{z-index:10;}
.z2{z-index:5;}
.z3{z-index:0;}. See updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

We’ll render the shadow in a pseudoelement (could be either `before` or `after`, it doesn’t matter) and assign a negative z-index to it.

```
.container{ 
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 20px 5px #000;
}
```

**For more details** - [Tutorial Here](https://blog.dudak.me/2014/css-shadows-under-adjacent-elements/).

Answer (score -1):

Change your css code for this

```css
h1{margin:0;}
.container{
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: There is no difference.